# Multidimensional Arrays in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I was trying to replicate the following code

[Drawing Multidimensional Array Using Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295006/drawing-multidimensional-array-using-tikz/394006#394006)

However, I was curious to know if I could add the letter U and zeros randomly instead of 0s and 1s. Is there a way to do this? I am trying to fill an array with 0s and utilities. Additionally wanted the array to face the other direction as I currently have(code below). the commented parts are attempts to place the nodes in the three dimensions

```
                \draw (0, 0, 0) -- (0, 0, 10) (4, 0, 0) -- (4, 0, 10);
        \foreach \z in {0, 5, 10} \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
        \foreach \y [evaluate={\b=random(0, 1);}] in {0,...,3}
        \filldraw [fill=white] (\x, \y, \z) -- (\x+1, \y, \z) -- (\x+1, \y+1, \z) --
        (\x, \y+1, \z) -- cycle (\x+.5, \y+.5, \z) node [yslant=tan(15)] {\b};
        \draw [dashed] (0, 4, 0) -- (0, 4, 10) (4, 4, 0) -- (4, 4, 10);
%       \draw [->] (0, 4.5, -1)  -- (4, 4.5, -1)   node [near end, above left] {legislators};
        \node [align=center, left] at (1,4.3,-.01) {$1$};   
        \draw [dashed] (1, 4.3, -.01)  -- (3.5, 4.3, -.01);   
        \draw [->] (1, 4.5, -.01)  -- (3.5, 4.5, -.01);   
        \node [align=center, left] at (4,4.3,-.01) {$N$} node [left] {legislators};
    %       \draw [->] (-1.35, 4, 0)  -- (-1.35, 0, 0)   node [midway, left] {status};


        %\draw [->] (6, 4.5, 1) -- (6, 4.5, 10) node [near end, above right] {proposed};
```

[image: My output looks as follows]

Additionally, I need to add labels in all 3 dimensions(the image has "legislators", but the placement is not accurate)
first dimensions - s1 .... s_G (SQ)
second dimension - s'_1.......s'_G (Prop)
third dimension - 1...........N (Legislators)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Your link leads to your own "answer" to that question, not to one of the other answers, so it's not immediately clear which code you're referring to. And please always make a complete example, like the ones you see in that question and its answers, so that the code can be copied directly and compiled. (Not that it's necessarily always complicated to turn a snippet into a complete example, but: in some cases it's absolutely necessary to know what your setup looks like to be able to answer the question, and it's also boring/tedious to have to do it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to fiddle with the formulas, then switch to node based grid with names. You can place the nodes similarly referring to nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{choices}{{U}{0}}
\foreach \z in {0, 5, 10}{
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\z*0.75cm]
    \foreach \x in {0,...,3}{
      \foreach \y in {0,...,3}{
        \node[fill=white,minimum size=1cm-\pgflinewidth,draw] (n-\x-\y-\z) 
             at (\x+.5,\y+.5,\z) {\pgfmathrandomitem{\mynum}{choices}\mynum};
      }
    }
  \end{scope}
}
\draw[blue,thick] (n-0-3-0.north west) -- (n-0-3-10.north west);
\draw[red,thick] (n-0-0-0.south west) -- (n-0-0-10.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]